# Sea Glass look and feel acting strange when i create a jar file and open it on a different pc

Tags: java, jar, look-and-feel

Sea Glass look and feel acting strange when I create a jar file and open it on a different PC. I use the following code:

```
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel");
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

This works fine on my desktop even when I run the jar file. When open the jar file from my laptop or any other machine the GUI is blank and components start to appear when you move the mouse over them. The sea glass look and feel is there but acting strange.

Comment: Perhaps, you should catch the exception with a message or print trace.  You could fall back to a more common look and feel on an Exception.

Comment: i have tried that.none of the look and feel's work when the jar file is run on a different pc

Answer (score 0):

If you add sea glass jar file to your library,Create a folder inside your package and add sea glass jar file to the folder.